# Three Arrays and Subset Sum

Tags: algorithm, subset

> Array 1: 1 2 4 8 21
>
> Array 2: 3 5 6 7 19 20
>
> Array 3: 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18

There are 3 arrays.
We are adding numbers starting from 1.
If the number is equal to the sum of any subset, we can not add to it.

**For example:**

22 can not be added to any array.

> > Because 1 + 21 = 22, 3 + 19 = 22, 10 + 12 = 22

21 can not be added to array 2.

> > Because 3 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 21

7 can be added to array 2.

> > Because (3 + 5 != 7), (3 + 6 != 7), (5 + 6 != 7), (3 + 5 + 6 != 7) ...

Numbers should be added in order. (If I didn't add 22, I can't add 23)

**21 is the greatest number what I can add.**

**I want to add greater number.**

**Is there a solution for this problem?**

**What is proper name of this problem?**

Thanks...

Comment: What are you trying to find? All the numbers you can add?

Comment: Eamonn McEvoy, I want to add number what it is greater than 21. According to what I have heard, 22 can be add.

Comment: @alikoker: please explain "22 can be added". Clearly, it can't be added to any of the three arrays because there are subsets which sum to 22 in all of them.

Comment: Should be easy to write a program to calculate the sum of each subset. Quickly looking at array 2 you can add 58,59, anything 61 and over

Comment: I have written program, but 22 can't be add. Numbers should be added in order. If I didn't add 22, I can't add 23.

Comment: @alikoker: I see. so you are interested in finding some legal sequence of placements such that it terminates with the greatest possible number?

Comment: but you can't add number 3 also since 1+2 = 3 in array 1..... can you choose the starting number ?

Comment: Yes I can't add "3" to array 1. But i can add "3" to "array 2 or array 3". Because these arrays are empty. I can not choose starting number. I can add numbers starting from "1". "1" can be add any array. Also, numbers should be added in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this backtracking solution (it basically checks every possible distribution), we find that 21 is actually the biggest number you can add using 3 arrays. 
Notice that we are not trying to find the best solution but the maximum number we can add.

```
def solution(a1, a2, a3, ps1, ps2, ps3, i):
    # First we try to put it on array 1
    m1 = m2 = m3 = 0
    if i not in ps1:
        l = len(ps1)
        ps1.extend([s + i for s in ps1])
        a1.append(i)
        m1 = solution(a1, a2, a3, ps1, ps2, ps3, i+1)
        # Now we backtrack
        a1.pop()
        while(len(ps1) > l):
            ps1.pop()
    if i not in ps2:
        l = len(ps2)
        ps2.extend([s + i for s in ps2])
        a2.append(i)
        m2 = solution(a1, a2, a3, ps1, ps2, ps3, i+1)
        # Now we backtrack
        a2.pop()
        while(len(ps2) > l):
            ps2.pop()
    if i not in ps3:
        l = len(ps3)
        ps3.extend([s + i for s in ps3])
        a3.append(i)
        m3 = solution(a1, a2, a3, ps1, ps2, ps3, i+1)
        # Now we backtrack
        a3.pop()
        while(len(ps3) > l):
            ps3.pop()
    return max(i-1, m1, m2, m3)
```

Returns 21

Comment: I did the same thing and came to the same result, before seeing your answer. +1